# Converting all numbers in a python list to 1 or 0

Tags: python

I have a list of integers, it looks like this:

```
[10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
```

I need for this list, for every 0, it to stay 0 and every higher number to be 1.
Thus converting the above list to:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
for numbers in list:
   if number==0:
      number=0
   if number>1:
      number=1
```

however this gives me:

```
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: 'number' vs 'numbers'

Comment: -1 for claiming the code you posted gives the output you posted when it does no such thing. If you're having problems with some code, show the actual code you're running.

Comment: I timed the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788298/1561176 (Mine is faster)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> l = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
>>> [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in l]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

if you want to change existing list

```
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x >= 1: l[i] = 1
```

Comment: Timing for different answers available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788298/1561176)

Answer (score 11):

A simple list-comprehension

```
>>> l = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
>>> [1 if i else 0 for i in l]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

The reason your code was not working is because you are iterating (looping) through each item of the list, but not modifying the item in the original list, only the returned item.

---

Timers (In order of speed):

```
# my method: [1 if i else 0 for i in l]
>>> timeit.Timer('[1 if i else 0 for i in l]', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[1.4960370266417915, 1.457976119063474, 1.457053021255831]
# Roman Pekar: [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in l]
>>> timeit.Timer('[1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in l]', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[1.5296303022631434, 1.5041486202146075, 1.51295106957906]
# inspectorG4dget: [int(i>0) for i in myList]
>>> timeit.Timer('[int(i>0) for i in l]', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[5.0810576000558285, 4.865218180917736, 4.7859557786252935]
# Haidro: map(int, map(bool, l))
>>> timeit.Timer('map(int, map(bool, l))', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[5.725813168085608, 5.759308116913473, 5.549817013103507]
# alecxe: map(lambda x: int(x > 0), l)
>>> timeit.Timer('map(lambda x: int(x > 0), l)', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[7.054628605392196, 7.291914272244128, 7.223923128993391]
# inspectorG4dget: [int(bool(i)) for i in l]
>>> timeit.Timer('[int(bool(i)) for i in l]', setup='from __main__ import l').repeat()
[8.60473766374804, 8.537255398342722, 8.545150893104449]
```

Comment: If the numbers are not guaranteed to be non-negative, you'll need to use one of the versions that explicitly compare to 0.

Comment: In which case, as timed above, [Roman Pekar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788107/1561176) would be best suited. However, in the OP's question the function is written without a condition for what happens to negative numbers, also - it seems to be this is an attempt to "normalize" a list of values to those `with` a value and those `without` a value. A very common operation in mathematics. If this is not the case, I would be surprised.

Answer (score 8):

```
myList = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
newList = [int(i>0) for i in myList]
```

OR

```
newList = [int(bool(i)) for i in myList]
```

Comment: I like the second option with `int(bool(i))` because there's only typecasting and no checking (like `i>0` or some kind of `if`/`else`) in any way.

Comment: @rednaw: yeah, there's no branching in that one, so it promises to be faster (though I haven't tested the `timeit`s)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I timed the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788298/1561176 (Mine is faster)

Comment: @InbarRose: intriguing. I wonder if the ternary operator is somehow uber optimized

Comment: @inspectorG4dget function calls in python aren't free, the less you make - the better. :)

Comment: The `bool` option requires the numbers to be non-negative (which does seem to be implied, though).

Comment: @InbarRose: function calls aren't, but this was type casting and `bool`s were a subclass of `int`s in 2.7, so I thought that would be faster

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` instead of list comprehension approach:

```
>>> l = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
>>> map(lambda x: int(x > 0), l)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Also see: [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: list comprehension is faster here, I timed the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788298/1561176

Comment: @InbarRose, great, thanks for tests - deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `numbers` variable when creating a `for` loop, but then you are comparing `number` (no 's') variable.

Also, avoid using `list` as a list name; give it some other name (e.g. a_list, or something descriptive).

Others have already provided you with good answers. Just in case you have a hard time understanding [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), this is what you tried to do:

```
old_list = [1, 5, 0, 0, 2]
new_list = []
for each_element in old_list:
    if each_element == 0:
        new_list.append(0)
    else:
        new_list.append(1) # what about negative numbers?
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_list = [0 if each_element == 0 else 1 for each_element in a_list]
```

You can also "modify" (overwrite) existing list on the fly:

```
a_list = [0 if each_element == 0 else 1 for each_element in a_list]
```

Comment: Why was this upvoted? I encourage the upvoter to run the code and see what happens. Hint: `number` is a local variable set to each value in the list, not some magical pointer to the object in the list. Changing it won't change the list.

Comment: My bad, I removed the code completely.

Answer (score 1):

Use map:

```
L = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
print map(int, map(bool, L))
```

Booleans are subclasses of integers, thus `False == 0` and `True == 1`. Calling `int()` on a bool will return either one or zero for true or false, respectively.

Note that in Python 3, map returns an iterator. So you should call `list()` on the outside `map()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
nums = [10, 8, 4, 4, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4]
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]: nums[i] = 1
```