# Getting 0 and 1s (integer bools) from a numeric numpy array in the the most efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

I have non-small (10^6) numpy arrays which I then make some computations on. One of the functions simply returns 0 if the value is larger than some value X or return 1 otherwise. I understand this a simple bool check does the job:

```
x = np.arange(100)
x = np.array(x > X, dtype=int)
```

However, given that I'm creating a new array and making conversions it seems very wasteful. Any ideas on how to do in place? Something along the lines of x.round() (but that would return either 0 or 1).

Or are my concerns completely unfounded?

Thanks!
P

PS: Yes, numpy is as requirement.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17788079/198633) out?

Comment: Actually did not see that before, thanks. But I really want to do it within numpy. Already have is as a np array so no point in making lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite frequently, you can get away with passing around the `bool` array. When used in arithmetic operations against numerical arrays, the `bool` array will be upcast as required, treating `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`.

But if you really need the most efficient way to get a true `int` array, use the `np.greater()` ufunc. Like all ufuncs, it accepts an `out=` keyword argument that will be used as a pre-allocated array to stuff the results into. It will convert each element on-the-fly so there is no intermediate `bool` array being created.

```
[~]
|1> import numpy as np

[~]
|2> x = np.arange(10)

[~]
|3> output = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=int)

[~]
|4> np.greater(x, 5, out=output)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

[~]
|5> output
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: This seems to be what I want. I can even do a 'np.greater(x, 5, out=x)' and keep just one array. Thanks!