# Convert list values to boolean

Tags: python, list

What I want to convert is something like this

```
a = [ 0, 10, 3, 2, 0, 2 ]

def covert_to_boolean(a)
     ...
    return a_converted

a_coverted = [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

what would be the easiest way to convert like this?

Comment: Your values in `a_coverted` aren't Booleans. They're just small integers. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could do it with a list comprehension, or do you need a function? Also, Python has True and False values for Booleans

Comment: I think I found the answer after write this question.

np.array([t>0 for t in a]) * 1

thank you.

Comment: @Chris yes they are not actually Booleans.. this another conversion to an integer as well.

Comment: How do you decide which values should convert to `True` and which should convert to `False`?

Comment: @Tae list comprehension is the way to go. see my answer

Comment: See: [Converting all numbers in a python list to 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788079/7851470)

Answer (score 7):

To convert to true Booleans, you could just use:

```
def covert_to_boolean(a)
    return [bool(x) for x in a]
```

This returns

```
[False, True, True, True, False, True]
```

If you'd prefer them as 0s and 1s, then:

```
    return [int(bool(x)) for x in a]
```

Would return:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Not actually suggesting this unless the code is the hottest code in your program, but there are ways to improve on:

```
def covert_to_boolean(a)
    return [bool(x) for x in a]
    # Or the straightforward way of converting back to 1/0
    return [int(bool(x)) for x in a]
```

First off, if `a` is large enough, since `int`/`bool` are built-ins implemented in C, you can use `map` to remove byte code interpreter overhead:

```
def covert_to_boolean(a)
    return [*map(bool, a)]
    # Or converting back to 1/0
    return [*map(int, map(bool, a))]
```

Another savings can come from not using the `bool` constructor (C constructor calls have unavoidable overhead on CPython, even when the result doesn't actually "construct" anything), and replacing it with `operator.truth` (a plain function taking exactly one argument, which CPython heavily optimizes) reduces overhead significantly, and using it can reduce overhead by 40%:

```
>>> import random
>>> from operator import truth
>>> a = random.choices([*[0] * 100, *range(1, 101)], k=1000)
>>> %%timeit -r5
... [bool(x) for x in a]
...
...
248 µs ± 7.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %%timeit -r5
... [*map(bool, a)]
...
...
140 µs ± 2.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5
... [*map(truth, a)]
...
...
81.3 µs ± 3.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`map(bool` improved on the list comprehension by about 45%, and was in turn beat by `map(truth` by 40% (`map(truth` took almost exactly one third the time of the list comprehension).

If the result must be an `int`, we could expand it to `[*map(int, map(truth, a))]`, but again, `int` is a constructor, and even though it returns singleton values (CPython caches single copies of -5 through 256 as an implementation detail), it still pays constructor overhead (worse, because it can take keyword arguments). There is no equivalent "convert to true `int`" function like `bool` has `operator.truth`, but you can cheat your way into one by "adding to `0`":

```
>>> %%timeit -r5
... [int(bool(x)) for x in a]
...
...
585 µs ± 65.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5
... [*map(int, map(bool, a))]
...
...
363 µs ± 58.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5
... [*map((0).__add__, map(truth, a))]
...
...
168 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`(0).__add__` just takes advantage of the fact that adding a `bool` to `0` produces either `0` or `1`, and `__add__` has far lower overhead than a constructor; in this case, the switch from list comprehension to `map` (even nested `map`) saved nearly 40%, switching from `int`/`bool` to `(0).__add__`/`truth` saved nearly 55% off what remained, for a total reduction in runtime of over 70%.

Again, to be clear, **don't do this** unless:

1. You've profiled, and converting really is the critical path in your code, speed-wise, and
2. The inputs aren't too small (if `a` were only a five elements, the setup overhead for calling `map` would outweigh the tiny savings from avoiding byte code per loop)

but when it comes up, it's good to know about. `bool` is one of the slowest things in Python, in terms of overhead:productive work ratio; `int` of already `int`-like things is similarly bad.

There is one last thing to check though. Maybe pushing things to syntax, avoiding function calls, might save more. As it happens, the answer is "it does, for one of them":

```
>>> %%timeit -r5
... [not not x for x in a]  # Worse than map
...
...
122 µs ± 6.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5
... [0 + (not not x) for x in a]  # BETTER than map!!!
...
...
158 µs ± 22.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit -r5
...: [0 + x for x in map(truth, a)]  # Somehow not the best of both worlds...
...:
...:
177 µs ± 5.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

While `[not not x for x in a]` lost to `[*map(truth, a)]`, `[0 + (not not x) for x in a]` actually beat `[*map((0).__add__, map(truth, a))]` (as it happens, there is some overhead in `(0).__add__` being invoked through a wrapper around the `tp_add` slot which can be avoided by actually using `+` at the Python layer). Mixing the best of each solution (`map(truth` with `0 +` in list comp) didn't actually benefit us though (readding the bytecode overhead was roughly a fixed cost, and `not not` beats even `operator.truth`). Point is, none of this is worth it unless you actually need it, and performance can be unintuitive. I had code that needed it, once upon a time, so you benefit from my testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `and` operator in a list comprehension to keep the code both fast and readable:

```
def covert_to_boolean(a)
    return [i and 1 for i in a]
```

This approach is faster than @ShadowRanger's fastest approach, as demonstrated here:
https://repl.it/@blhsing/NeglectedClientsideLanserver

Comment: Ah, nice. Takes advantage of the values already being `int`. My approach is more general (works with any input, not just `int`), but yeah, it does needlessly convert to `bool` and back when half the values are already correct. When the desired result is `True`/`False`, `[*map(truth, a)]` beats this, but this beats my solutions that end up as `1`/`0`.

Comment: Note that your test case is for a fairly small input; if you want asymptotic performance to avoid overweighting setup costs, I'd suggest going with a much longer `a` (if you're only doing small `a` anyway, the performance doesn't matter much). I went with 1000 elements for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

### **2 Half line solutions:**

```
def covert_to_boolean(a):
    return [1 if i !=0 else 0 for i in a]
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

#OR
def covert_to_boolean(a):
    return [bool(i)*1 for i in a]
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Why bother with `True*1`/`False*1` when you can just do `1`/`0`: `[1 if i !=0 else 0 for i in a]`. The `*1` trick is useful if you had to have a boolean (e.g. `[(i != 0)*1 for i in a]`), though `+0` uses a cheaper fake operation, but as long as you're using ternary selection, it's unnecessary.

Comment: true initially I thought the OP wanted boolean output so I built my answer that way, then I saw the 0/1 and to fix it fast I did BOOL*1/0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wanted b or c, so here's both

```
>>> a = [ 0, 10, 3, 2, 0, 2 ]
>>> b = [bool(i) for i in a]
>>> b
[False, True, True, True, False, True]
>>> c = [int(bool(i)) for i in a]
>>> c
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the lapses in terminology; here is a solution using list comprehension that you can study (assuming you are a student):

```
a=[2,0,12,45,0,0,99]
b=[1 if i != 0 else 0 for i in a]
print b
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: this is not boolean

Comment: I think the example makes it clear what the OP needs

Comment: @makis: It's not boolean, but it's what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert your values to 0 and 1, I think the most elegant way would be:

```
a_converted = [1 if e else 0 for e in a]
```

where you basically check `if e`, meaning e is non-zero and assign 1, vs it being zero and assign 0, for each `e` in `a`.